# GPO - Windows 10 - Set accent color to auto from background

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Title says it all really. How do I set the accent color to the auto option in a GPO?

Answer (score 1):

There's *Force a specific background and accent color* under *Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control panel > Personalization*, but it can only force the color to be a specific color 
(for example company color) or let the user choose (default / disable).

> Forces Windows to use the specified colors for the background and
>   accent. The color values are specified in hex as #RGB.
>
> By default, users can change the background and accent colors.
>
> If this setting is enabled, the background and accent colors of
>   Windows will be set to the specified colors and users cannot change
>   those colors. This setting will not be applied if the specified colors
>   do not meet a contrast ratio of 2:1 with white text.

I assume that by "auto" you mean the *Automatically pick an accent color from my background* setting on Windows 10 *Settings > Personalization > Colors*. It seems to toggle a HKCU key (0=>1):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoColorization"=dword:00000001
```

You may try to change that (with *User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry*). Naturally, as a HKCU setting, it needs to be applied to users rather than computers.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this have a side effect: Users unable to name new folders or rename existing folders, and scrollbars appeared to randomly snap back to the top of a window.

If there is a slideshow set for the background, and "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" is checked, every time the background image changes, it will refresh windows, especially Windows Explorer, and pop the scrollbar back to the top. If  you are in the process of renaming a file or folder (or just created a new folder and are typing the name for it), and the background changes, this refresh kicks you out of that operation, and the folder name remains the same or is set to "New Folder".

I had a user with this issue, but the only symptom initially noticed was with creating a new folder. Once he mentioned the scroll bar snapping back to the top, I was able to get a google hit on my searches.

The environment this happened in was Citrix sessions, both Windows 8 and Windows 10 experiences. It may handle it better on a physical machine.